# Unknown monitor in Lenovo laptop

Tags: display, fedora

I have set of two Lenovo laptops on which Fedora core 13 is installed. On one machine, the monitor is detected properly such that it is possible to connect another monitor. But on another laptop, the monitor is shown as unknown monitor. I tried to fix it by reinstalling  xorg-x11-drv-intel.i686. But the problem remains same (unknown monitor) and it is not possible to connect another monitor with this setting.

Laptop model: Lenovo G460.
Graphics card: Intel Graphics Media accelerator HD.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the word nomodeset in grub.conf

rename xorg.conf to xorg.conf.nomoreused

Just reboot Fedora ... now adapter is detected properly.